# How do I delete local row data and maintain pagination with jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jqgrid

I have a multi-page table using jqGrid. I use `$obj.jqGrid('delRowData',id)` to delete all the rows on the first page (the function is called for every row selected). However, the end result is an empty first page with the second which in my mind should become the first page now left as it is untouched. Is there something else I need to call to consolidate the pages in the grid?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: We are using jqGrid 4.5.2